# Weird behaviour from Magento currency selector

Tags: magento, currency

We're having an unusual issue with Magento on our live site which we're unable to replicate with our local one.

When you select the currency you want to use, you're redirected to a random page on the site, and although it appears the currency is set correctly, returning to the selector, rather than the currently selected currency being auto-selected, it's defaulting to whatever currency is at the top of the list.

The URL to our site is: http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb

You can reach the currency selector by clicking on the flag in the top right-hand corner of the site.

As I said, I've tried to replicate the error on our local server, but have been unable to.

**UPDATE**

I think I've found the cause of the second issue (that of the chosen currency not being selected). This is a side effect of the selector being in the footer, and caching being turned on. We're solving this by replacing the drop-down with currency icons.

**UPDATE 2**

I think I've worked out the cause of the first issue (i.e. being redirected to a random page). This IS because of the `uenc` value passed in the URL, which appears to reference the last page visited, but because this is also being cached, the data it contains is incorrect/not up to date (hence the random page).

Comment: I am redirected to http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb/images/signatures/SSLOGO.png with 404 error.

Comment: Yes, me too... No idea why - although, it seems (like @McNab suggests) if you remove the `uenc` part of the URL, it works fine. I'm playing with a potential solution now.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with your findings, sounds like you got it sorted in the end (or are about to :))

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I've actually just moved the block to the header (from the footer) and that seems to have fixed all the issues. I'll add an answer myself once I've figured it all out.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but I need the space (I'll delete it if it's wrong, I might be totally wrong here).  I am suspecting you've upgraded the site to 1.8, there are changes relating to encoding of urls.  If you look at the generated markup it is;

```
<select id="select-currency" name="currency" title="Select Your Currency" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <option value="http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb/directory/currency/switch/currency/GBP/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zY2hvb2xzdGlja2Vycy5jb20vZW4tZ2IvaW1hZ2VzL3NpZ25hdHVyZXMvU1NMT0dPLnBuZw,,/" selected="selected">
                    British Pound Sterling - GBP</option>
    <option value="http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb/directory/currency/switch/currency/EUR/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zY2hvb2xzdGlja2Vycy5jb20vZW4tZ2IvaW1hZ2VzL3NpZ25hdHVyZXMvU1NMT0dPLnBuZw,,/">
                    Euro - EUR</option>
    <option value="http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb/directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zY2hvb2xzdGlja2Vycy5jb20vZW4tZ2IvaW1hZ2VzL3NpZ25hdHVyZXMvU1NMT0dPLnBuZw,,/">
                    US Dollar - USD</option>
</select>
```

However if you modify that to remove the `uenc` part then this url will switch currency;

```
http://www.schoolstickers.com/en-gb/directory/currency/switch/currency/EUR/
```

This post is related I think, there are a few other on SO too

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/buy-now-url-doesnt-work-on-magento-1-8-solved

Comment: Actually, we're still running 1.7.0.2 - however, having looked at your suggestion of removing the `uenc` part of the URL seems to have fixed the first issue (of being redirected to a non-existent page) - I just need to figure out how to modify magento to have this removed from the URLs in the select box. This doesn't, however, seem to fix the second issue (i.e. the chosen currency not being selected in the drop down).